# Как синхронизировать данные из 1 таблицы в другую

Tags: php, база-данных, laravel, eloquent

Предположим есть тз:

- Сделать таблицу с настройками магазина
  Что уже есть:
- Заполненая таблица market в которой есть колонки

`id | name | director | adress | type`

В настройках должна быть настройка работы магазина в тот или иной день, время открытия и закрытия и прочее. Это не суть. Суть в том, что на front это будет как табличка из всех складов с их настройками заполненными или пустыми

Сейчас я реализовал этом по средствам rightJoin таблицы market_settings и market, получив все магазины и значения колонок приравненные к null (потому что данных нет)

Как можно более изящно решить эту проблему? Как вариант смотрел в сторону event модели в laravel, например навешать на creating event создание записи и во второй таблицы, но не уверен насколько это правильно.